# Webkit not found on OSX

Tags: macos, webkit, configure, pkg-config, mu

I'm trying to compile [mu](https://github.com/djcb/mu) that uses the headers `webkit/webkitwebview.h` and `webkit/webkitwebresource.h`. The OSX version of webkit framework located in `/System/Library/Frameworks` doesn't seem to have it, the headers are different and use NS data types and stuff.

So I downloaded webkit-gtk with MacPorts (since it's not available through Homebrew) and pointed `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to `webkit-1.0.pc`. I verified and this version has the needed headers.

But the problem is, I still get an error, the configure file doesn't seem to be able to find it.

`checking for WEBKIT... no`

I don't even know, actually, if `webkit-1.0.pc` is the package config it is looking for.

I had two other compilation problems prior to this, with `glib.h` and `gtk.h` but managed to go through. This is the last issue I need to resolve to have a fully functional email client in Emacs.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me [1]:

add this to ~/.profile (or wherever you take care of this stuff):

```
# ~/.profile stuff
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig/:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
```

then source:
`$ source ~/.profile`

then (assuming you're in the `mu` dir) voila [2]:
`$ ./configure`

[1] i have gtk installed via homebrew, installed webkit-gtk3 via macports, and cloned `mu` from the github repo. running os x 10.9.5

[2] here's the `$ ./configure` output:

```
mu configuration is complete.
------------------------------------------------
mu version                           : 0.9.10

Xapian version                       : 1.2.19
GLib version                         : 2.42.1
GMime version                        : 2.6.20
GTK+ version                         : 3.14.5
Webkit version                       : 2.4.7
Emacs version                        : GNU Emacs 24.4.51.1

Have wordexp                         : yes
Build mu4e emacs frontend            : yes
Build 'mug' toy-ui (gtk+/webkit)     : yes
McCabe's Cyclomatic Complexity tool  : no

Have direntry->d_ino                 : yes
Have direntry->d_type                : yes
------------------------------------------------
```